# EntityManager not injected

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

I'm getting an NPE for my EntityManager and can't figure out why - can anyone spot my mistake?

UserManagerImpl.java

```
@Stateless
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
 EntityManager em;

 public List<User> findUsers() {
  return (List<User>) em.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
 }
}
```

META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

These are inside my ejb jar project, the UserManagerImpl is invoked from a JSP, not sure that should make a difference though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which server are you running on ?

Comment: Are you using JBoss? With HSQLDB? What do you get in the server logs?

Comment: JBoss with HSQLDB, can't see anything of significance in the server log.

I suspect it might be because I'm referencing UserManager from my JSP using new UserManagerImpl() but I'm not sure how to inject it into a managed bean if so, using an annotation. Not sure it is that anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `new UserManagerImpl()` the container has no way to inject the `EntityManager` into this class. You need to let the container inject an instance into your object using

```
@EJB
private UserManager userManager;
```

This will only work for container managed objects like JSF managed beans, servlets or JSPs. Alternatively you can look up the ejb from jndi using something like

```
new InitialContext().lookup("UserManagerImpl");
```

The actual jndi name might be different.